# Приведите пример использования Volatile.Read,Write

Tags: c#, многопоточность, language-lawyer

Я опробовал в интернете множество примеров,но они не показывают на практике,разницу работы одного и того-же кода с применением Volatile и без.Можно ли на персональном компьютере осуществить это,или разницу можно  увидеть только при работе сервера с множеством клиентов,которые одновременно используют и изменяют одну и туже переменную через разные потоки?

Comment: и не забывайте, что volatile не гарантирует атомарность.

Comment: А вот это уже печально.А что-то может её гарантировать?

Comment: Interlocked может. Monitor может. Просто многие считают, что volatile автоматом обеспечивает атомарность,  а это не так.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример.

```
class Program
{
    static bool finish = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
        int x = 0;
        while (!finish)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }

    static void ThreadProc()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        finish = true;
    }
}
```

Откомпилируйте Release, запустите из командной строки (**не** из Visual Studio), увидите, что программа не завершается. Поменяйте код на такой:

```
class Program
{
    static bool finish = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
        int x = 0;
        while (!Volatile.Read(ref finish)) // while (!finish)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }

    static void ThreadProc()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Volatile.Write(ref finish, true); // finish = true;
    }
}
```

— этот код будет завершаться.

Идея примера честно украдена из [ответа Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/458193/276994).

---

Пояснение. Многопоточные проблемы с обновлением данных между потоками возникают не только из-за оптимизации на уровне процессора (вид разных процессоров многопроцессорной системы на оперативную память может быть различным), а и из-за оптимизаций компилятора, который имеет право (это важно!) переставлять операции, если только смысл кода в каждом отдельном потоке не меняется.

В обычном случае х86-системы с достаточно сильной моделью памяти процессор таких трюков почти не делает, так что проблемы нам с вами видны не так часто, в отличие от программистов на ARM, например. А вот оптимизации компилятора, наоборот, становятся всё агрессивнее и агрессивнее, хотя и в рамках стандарта языка.

Право компилятора на изменение внутреннего смысла кода известно как as-if rule: компилятор может производить любой код, если только его побочные эффекты *в каждом отдельном потоке* оставались те же и в том же порядке. В частности, компилятор имеет право выбросить повторное чтение переменной, если он видит, что она *в данном потоке* не меняется.

Однако некоторые операции (например, `Volatile.Read`/`Write`, `lock`, `Thread.Start`/`Join` и т. п.) являются *критическими точками*, и оптимизации проводятся лишь в блоках между такими точками.

В нашем случае оптимизатор смог понять, что переменная `finish` *с точки зрения основного потока* не меняется, и выкинул повторное чтение. Имел на это полное право.

Когда мы добавили `Volatile`-операции, то компилятор более не имел права не перечитывать переменную, так что изменения были «замечены».

---

Ссылки на C# Language Specification

(раздел 3.10):

> Execution of a C# program proceeds such that the side effects of each executing thread are preserved at critical execution points. [...] The execution environment is free to change the order of execution of a C# program, subject to the following constraints:
>
> - Data dependence is preserved within a thread of execution. That is, the value of each variable is computed as if all statements in the thread were executed in original program order.
> - Initialization ordering rules are preserved (§10.5.4 and §10.5.5).
> - The ordering of side effects is preserved with respect to volatile reads 
>     and writes (§10.5.3). [...]

(раздел 10.5.3):

> For non-volatile fields, optimization techniques that reorder instructions can lead to unexpected and unpredictable results in multi-threaded programs that access fields without synchronization such as that provided by the lock-statement (§8.12). These optimizations can be performed by the compiler, by the run-time system, or by hardware.

Comment: а почему это можно заметить только в `Release`?

Comment: @Lightness: Потому что в Debug оптимизатор менее агрессивен.

Comment: Хмм, буду знать.

Comment: @VladD, а если поле finish пометить оператором volatile - эффект будет тот же?

Comment: Компилятор не выкидывает чтение `finish`, посмотрите IL. Есть у Вас объяснение, почему код в бесконечный цикл входит?

Comment: @ixSci, возможно версия .NET другая или оптимизация идет на этапе JIT выполнения?

Comment: @Alexis: Насколько я понимаю, да.

Comment: @ixSci: Разумеется, оптимизации проводит JITter. Посмотрите в нативный код.

Comment: @ixSci: http://pastebin.com/nz0w2xbM

Comment: @FaradeyInimicos: А в чём вопрос?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/47Levan/ac7880d71475b7cb085ffdee3b733be8 .Почему тот же пример,только реализованный через отдельный класс,не работает по тому же принципу?Самое смешное,что я его написал до того как этот вопрос задать на сайте.Почему это работает только через Main метод?

Comment: @FaradeyInimicos: Потому что оптимизатор **не обязан** оптимизировать повторное чтение. Иногда он это делает, иногда нет, имеет полное право. В вашем случае увеличение статической, а не локальной переменной произвело на него какой-то эффект. В любом случае, спецификация говорит, что ожидать какого-то определённого эффекта нельзя. Пользуйтесь `lock`'ом для разделяемых переменных во избежание неприятных неожиданностей.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,причина действительно была в статической Int varInc,сделал локальной и всё заработало.Вообщем,как я понял на всякий случай лучше Volatile использовать,когда много потоков используют одну и туже переменную.

Comment: @FaradeyInimicos: Да, а в сложных случаях я бы посоветовал `lock`. // Пожалуйста!